# Deprecation Warnings on Dynamic fields in a table

Tags: ruby, devexpress, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am getting the DEPRECATION WARNING on a text_field call.
The text field is embedded in a DevExtreme table and out devs cannot put any unique IDs on it. (field is a filter row text box)
the table cell has about 5 layers of Div tags before the text box.

Table def:

```
table(:participant_table_header, :id => 'ParticipantsGridHeader')
```

call getting warning:

```
self.participant_table_header_element[1]['Employee ID'].text_field.value = data.employee_id
```

I have tried several permutations, .value and _element.set both work but give the warning.  All other methods I have tried fail to populate the field.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Page Object gem, the nested element method is `text_field_element` rather than `text_field`.

```
self.participant_table_header_element[1]['Employee ID'].text_field_element.value = data.employee_id
```

Comment: I must have missed that combination. Thank you,  that works.